# Using c function to filtering a dataframe with more than 2 characters Conditions

Tags: r, multiple-conditions

I know the c function is a generic function which combines its arguments. The problem that I encountered is about the c function with more than 2 characters in r. The question and example as below:

**Step 1**: I create a data frame with 2 columns Region and Salary.

```
> x<-data.frame(Region=c("a","b","c","c","a","b"),Salary=c(11:16))
> x
  Region Salary
1      a     11
2      b     12
3      c     13
4      c     14
5      a     15
6      b     16
```

**Step 2**: I can get the correct answer when I chose one region(EX:a or b or c).

```
> x[x$Region=="a",]
  Region Salary
1      a     11
5      a     15
> x[x$Region=="c",]
  Region Salary
3      c     13
4      c     14
```

**Step 3**: If I choose the multiple region (EX:(a,b),(a,c),(b,c),(a,b,c)), the result would be unpredictable.

```
x[x$Region==c("a","c"),]
  Region Salary
1      a     11
4      c     14
5      a     15
```

**Question**: I thought the c function is "combine" its arguments. So the result of `x[x$Region==c("a","c"),]` would be the same as the result of `x[x$Region=="a" | x$Region=="c",]`. But it turns out only show the row 1,4,5...Where is row 3??

What does `x[x$Region==c("a","c"),]` mean??

Thanks for your time

Comment: you need `?match`

Comment: Hi Cath, I know I can use %in% to find the answer. I just want to know what does c("a","c") means?  Is it mean "a" & "c" or "a" | "c" or it means nothing or it has other meaning? Thanks~~

Comment: it means a vector whose first element is "a" and second element is "c"

Comment: Thanks Cath. I suddenly got the point !! It doesn't  matter what is c("a","c"). The point is I should use %in% instead of "==".  Thanks again Cath~